# Spring Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: java, spring-aop

I need to block a method execution based on outcome of Spring @Before Aspect. Is there any way I can accomplish this using Spring AOP support.

Given below is my Spring configuration:

```
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect id="icpt_da" ref="inboundWSRequestInterceptor">
     <aop:before method="interceptDataArrived" pointcut="execution(* com.emeter.ami.openway.delegate.MeterDataSubscriberServiceDelegate.dataArrived(..)) and args(dataArrivedDocument)" />
  </aop:aspect>
```

My intention is to avoid execution of method MeterDataSubscriberServiceDelegate.dataArrived based on outcome of aspect "inboundWSRequestInterceptor"

Thanks
Hitesh

Comment: set a boolean flag.... and do some when if(!flag){}

Comment: Hi I dont want to do it programmaticaly. If that was the case I would not have asked the question :). My intention is to achieve this through Spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to use @Before - you can use @Around advice and than make your verification inside of the method - than based on the result of it call proceed or not:

```
if(verificataionPassed){
   joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

For details on @Around you can look for example - [here](http://javarticles.com/2015/08/spring-aop-around-advice-annotation-example.html)